Gstreamer from local rtsp to public rtmp
I'm using Ubuntu on an AMD64 machine and running OBS to connect to a local camera using rtsp and then stream it to a public rtmp server. It works but the problem is that in OBS, rtsp is known to be unreliable and will lose the camera image or freeze after x amount of hours or days and then OBS ends up streaming a black screen. I need to keep monitoring it and when necessary, manually restart the rtsp source. I'm looking for a more reliable solution.
I have been reading about gstreamer which seems like a hopeful route but building the pipeline is complicated. I tried the following and it appears to work:
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://address" protocols=tcp latency=0 ! fakesink

now I just need to know how to parse this to the rtmp. An obstacle is that the source is 1280x720/10fps and the rtmp server is expecting 1280x720/25fps so there will need to be some kind of conversion in the middle. Would appreciate any suggestions. I have tried the below which almost works, but it throws out some errors. Important to mention that I don't need or want any audio.
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://address" protocols=tcp latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location='rtmp://address live=true' audiotestsrc is-live=true ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000 ! voaacenc bitrate=96000 ! audio/mpeg ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg, mpegversion=4 ! mux.


To have a 1280x720/25fps output, you can make the following adjustments to your pipeline:
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://address" protocols=tcp latency=0 ! "application/x-rtp" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videorate max-rate=25 ! "video/x-raw,framerate=25/1" ! x264enc ! flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location='rtmp://address live=true'

Note: I have removed audio-related elements since you mentioned audio is not important for your use case. You can re-add those parts at your discretion.
If you prefer to use your original pipeline, without re-encoding, you can also consider using variable frame rate capability from your RTSP source, "if present". You can configure your RTSP stream to have a maximum frame rate of 25 fps (also indicated in stream framerate metadata). This approach can help to allow dynamic frame rates up to 25 FPS. However, its important that the remote RTMP consumer should be able to handle such streams. Usually, not every RTMP servers or clients are equipped to manage VFRs effectively.
